# search in One2many custom field odoo

Tags: odoo, field, product

I install the model product_custom_info who add specified field to product (Custom Properties)

And Now I would create a filter  by this field ( It's one2many field)

Comment: Check this link https://codedump.io/share/hWoHUoTFveJa/1/how-to-fetch-values-from-a-one2many-field-in-odoo

Comment: Thanks , But I mean search by filter xml

Comment: It would be nice if you edit the question and make it more specific.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to use many2many field instead and you can make it searchable like the way you do to other fields (char, many2one etc.)

hope it helps